# How does injected JavaScript work within '{ }'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

In JSX, When we want to add JavaScript between JSX we use '{}', which indicates injected JavaScript.
I was wondering how does this work? How does '{}' treats as JavaScript? Is it different than '${}'? Which we use in string interpolation.

Comment: That's the compiler's job. That syntax is part of the JSX language, you might as well be asking how does the `var` keyword work

Answer (score 0):

In short it's tokenize, parse and make abstract syntax tree AST. this {} it is one of allowed expressions. but you can just imagine that its call eval()

but if you are so curious

[React under the hood](https://github.com/Bogdan-Lyashenko/Under-the-hood-ReactJS)

[Deconstructing React || Tejas Kumar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2mMOiCSj5c)

Answer (score 0):

JSX is just a [syntactic sugar for `React.createElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html), it transpiled by babel, so you can check how inner scope treated with [babel playground](https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?browsers=defaults%2C%20not%20ie%2011%2C%20not%20ie_mob%2011&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=DwEwlgbgfAUABHA3gcgJIDt0FMBOcDKAxgPYAOWyAvjMAPTjRA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.12.3&externalPlugins=):

```
<div>
  {'Inner Scope'}
</div>
```

Which transpiled to:

```
React.createElement("div", null, 'Inner Scope');
```

That means, the answer to "How does '{}' treats as JavaScript" is by passing the inner scope to `React.createElement` - `children` agrument.

```
React.createElement(
  type,
  [props],
  [...children]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

They are pretty similar. In JSX, when you're in the middle of writing JSX markup, and the interpreter comes across `{someExpression}`, it will indeed evaluate `someExpression` as JavaScript (rather than JSX markup) and either:

- Interpolate the resulting expression into the markup as a string, if in the context of a React child, eg:

  ```
  <div>
  {someExpression}
  </div>
  ```

  This **is** exactly the same thing that `${}` does inside a template literal. As React docs [show](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html):

  ```
  <div>Hello {this.props.toWhat}</div>
  ```

  compiles to

  ```
  return React.createElement('div', null, `Hello ${this.props.toWhat}`);
  ```
- Or, if in the context of a prop, the expression will be passed as a prop to the component there, eg:

  ```
  <div onClick={someExpression}> 
  </div>
  ```

  This is *not* interpolation, but it indicates to the compiler to pass the resulting expression as a part of an object, as props. For example:

  ```
  <Hello toWhat={SomeExpression} />,
  ```

  gets compiled to

  ```
  React.createElement(Hello, {toWhat: SomeExpression}, null),
  ```